# SQL Query in LIKE Clause - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

I have a single column table with numeric values - STORE

```
STORE
5546
7453
```

I have another table with 2 columns - ERROR_LOG

```
ID ERROR
1  Error matching the 5546 transfer zone 
2  Error matching the 7453 supplier
```

I want to check if the values in stores table exist in the ERROR column of the ERROR_LOG table.

Is there a way to put sql query in a LIKE clause? or it can only be done matching one by one?

Comment: For example, use `like` in `on` clause of the `join`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
select *
from ERROR_LOG EL
join STORE SS
on EL.ERROR like '%' || SS.STORE ||'%'
```

Comment: Maybe add blanks, so as to have 5546 not match 155461. No problem of course in case all store numbers are 4 digits.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend that you include delimiters on both sides:

```
select *
from ERROR_LOG EL join
     STORE SS
     on ' ' || EL.ERROR || ' ' like '% ' || SS.STORE || ' %'
```

If your error codes are not always four digits long, then they can be confused with each other.  They could also be confused with other values in the string, such as a date.